# CSS fluid two column and min-width

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I have a two-column fluid layout, with the left-hand side set to `width: 40%` and the right-hide side set to `width: 60%`. I'd like to allow users to resize their browser as large or small as they'd like, but I must have the left-hand side display a **minimum width of `300px`**.

The following is the code I am currently using for the fluid layout, which includes the `min-width` specification. But, CSS is ignoring it! It allows the left-hand column to shrink below `300px`.

I've also attempted to set `min-width` to a percentage, such as `20%`, but CSS ignores this specification as well.

```
div#left {
background: #ccc;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0; 
left: 0;
width: 40%;
min-width:300px;
height: 100%;
}

div#right {
background: #aaa;
position: fixed;
top: 0; 
width:60%;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
​
```

**jsFiddle Fullscreen Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/umgvR/3/embedded/result/

**jsFiddle Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/umgvR/3/

What is causing this? How can the code be corrected?

Comment: What is supposed to happen with the right div when the min-width for the left is reached?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not too attached to the fixed positioning, this should do what you want.

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vygfN/)

### HTML

```
<div id="left">Left</div><div id="right">Right</div>
```

*Note the lack of whitespace between the elements*

### CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-width: 800px;
}
div#left {
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  min-width:300px;
  height: 100%;
}

div#right {
  background: #aaa;
  display: inline-block;
  width:60%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should also work...

html

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="left">Left</div>
        <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

css

```
body, div {width:100%;
                height:100%;
                margin: 0;
            }

            #container {
                display:block;position: fixed;
            }
            #left, #right {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            div#left {
                background: #ccc;
                min-width: 300px;
                max-width: 40%;
            }

            div#right {position:fixed;
                background: #aaa;
                width: 60%;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the left hand div is keeping the minimum width, but its going underneath the right div. If you bring it forward, you can see it on top of the right div. I don't think that this is ideal though.

```
 z-index: 1;
```

I used z-index: 1; on the left right and z-index: 0; on the right div.

It works but I think there are better solutions out there.

Comment: I just realised, the right hand div is going underneath the left hand div when the min-width comes into play. Will try and look into it some more.